# Express - All declarations of 'user' must have identical modifiers

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am making use of `express` and `passport` in my application, In both packages, there's a `user` attribute under the `Request` interface. Currently, `express` has a `user` attribute but no other properties attached to it in the request object, e.g `req.user`. I am trying to do a declaration merge (not really sure if this is the right term for it) for express in order to tell typescript that `Express.Request.user` has an `id` attribute attached to it like so:

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    user: {
      id: string
    }
  }
}
```

At the same time also, `passport` has a `user` attribute but with the value of `Express.User`. When I do that declaration merge above, I get an error that says `All declarations of 'user' must have identical modifiers.` Here's the declaration file for `passport`.

```
interface User {}

        interface Request {
            authInfo?: AuthInfo;
            user?: User;

            // These declarations are merged into express's Request type
            login(user: User, done: (err: any) => void): void;
            login(user: User, options: any, done: (err: any) => void): void;
            logIn(user: User, done: (err: any) => void): void;
            logIn(user: User, options: any, done: (err: any) => void): void;

            logout(): void;
            logOut(): void;

            isAuthenticated(): this is AuthenticatedRequest;
            isUnauthenticated(): this is UnauthenticatedRequest;
        }
```

I understand it's because of a mismatch in the interfaces, but how do I overcome this? Any help is welcome. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue - I managed to get it working by adding properties directly to the `User` interface instead of `Request.user` -

In `@types/express/index.d.ts`

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface User {
      userId: number;
      name: string;
      email: string;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have declared/imported duplicated type that have the same props.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and struggled for an afternoon on it as well. I managed to make it work like so in my project:

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface User extends UserDocument {
      // A basic field so EsLint does not think it's an empty interface, 
      // and replace it with some other code which it thinks to be better
      // (cause for me, it was replacing automatically the line with 
      // "type User = UserDocument" which was making Typescript unhappy).
      // This field is useless, but that's the only solution I found.
      uselessField?: boolean;
    }
  }
}

// Alternatively, you can also substitute this line declaration with:
// "export type UserD = mongoose.Document & {"
// as seen in the Microsoft starter template: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter
// It works too.
export interface UserDocument extends mongoose.Document {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  // ... etc
}

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema<UserDocument>(
  {
    firstName: String;
    lastName: String;
    email: String;
    // ... etc
  },
);

export const User = mongoose.model<UserDocument>("User", UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error when I was trying to create my own interface called `Request`.

Typescript also has a [built-in `Request` interface](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.request.html)

The attributes in my interface conflicted with the already existing interface.

In such a case, the **solution is to just rename the interface** to something that has a low chance of already being defined